# Cannot find module [Yarn Environment Variables]

Tags: node.js, yarnpkg

I was having some issues with my React native application with Expo and I followed some tutorials to to change some environment variables for NPM. After that I started getting this error in my CLI:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yarn\bin\yarn.js'
[90m    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:880:15)[39m
[90m    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:725:27)[39m
[90m    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)[39m
[90m    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47[39m {
  code: [32m'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'[39m,
  requireStack: []
}
```

I tried installing Yarn with NPM but it brought up the same error.

I am not sure if the problem is from the path for Yarn in the environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following things:

1. install the latest Node.js
2. run `npm install -g expo-cli --force`

Comment: The code does not run in the cli. It just skips.

Comment: Is your Node.js version latest?